# Honda civic 2010 steering/body vibration after 99kmp

Tags: honda, civic, steering, vibration, body

My Civic vibrates after 99 kmp every time. If I forcely give acceleration in that speed range, I observe the vibration is less. Whenever I take my foot from accelerator pedal, it feels like more vibrating. Also, if I use cruise control, in 5 seconds after car rpm is stable, the vibration is less. Trouble shooted below things, but still the problem starts at 99 always:

- **4 new Dunlop Japan tires**
- **2 new wheel bearings front**
- **4 new suspension (since it was weak)**
- **Changed lower main (hydraulic mounting few months back)**
- **Performed balancing twice**

can somebody help

Comment: Can you feel the vibrations in the steering wheel?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "changed lower main" ... not sure what you're talking about there.

Comment: A bad tire (out of round or belt degradation) can cause this, balancing will not cure this, a good tire balance person would spot this visually during the balance process.

Comment: Thanku all for commenting. 
1.Yes vibration there on steering too @Zaid
2.@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 ,i mean the engine mounting ,the lower one ,when i had a body+steering vibration even when the cars was not moving also ,it cured that
3.@Moab as per tyre shop wheels and tires are in good condition(new too)

Comment: the vibration now starts from 100 ,if i accelerate hardly ,i feel less vibration and also vibration gets cool when i put cruise and wait for 10 secs. But keep vibrates always